# Getting rid of a ghost line underneath a dash pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following MWE, I wrote a command for exercises where I draw a line of points between the title and the amount of points. This line is drawn with a `dash pattern` and `rounded corners`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{exer}
\newenvironment{exercice}[2]
    {
    \addtocounter{exer}{1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \tikzset{titrex/.style={
            fill=red!20,
            right,
            draw=red!50!black,
            rounded corners=5pt,
            line width=1pt,
            inner xsep=10pt,
            minimum height=22pt}
            }
        
        \node[titrex,right] (A) at (0,0) {\textbf{\strut Exercice {\theexer}} ~~~ #2};
        \node[titrex,left] (B) at (\linewidth,0)    {
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}
                    {\hfill \textit{1~point}}
                    {\hfill \textit{#1~points}}
                };
        \draw[titrex] (2.5,-11pt) --++ (0,22pt);
        
        %---Here's where the issue lies
        \draw[titrex,line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 2.5\pgflinewidth] (A.east) -- (B.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace*{-2mm}      
    }
    
\begin{document}

\noindent
\exercice{6}{Deux configurations simples}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The dash pattern seems fine to me in the TeXmaker prview window:
[image: dash pattern 1]

But unfortunately, when I read it or print it from Acrobat reader, there are artefact of the line between the dots, and the dots are not that fine (could be necessary to enlarge the picture to see the issue):
[image: dash pattern 2]

As a side issue, you can see that the dots are not exactly positionned as in the preview.

This is neither an emergency nor absolutely necessary to be solved but I wondered if this was *normal* or if I could do it better.

Comment: You could try to switch off all these "thin line enhancement" settings etc. in acrobat reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac preview do not have any problems, but Acrobat Reader shows artefacts.
This code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill, line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 2.5\pgflinewidth] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

shows
[image: Dots with thin center line]

Using `fill=none` corrects the problem to this:

[image: Six dots in a row]

---

Adding `fill=none` to the problematic line, negating the style fill, also removes the artefact:

[image: Boxes with dotted line between]

I do not have TeXmaker, and I can not reproduce the shifted dot pattern observed.

Comment: I can see that there's still a shifting issue with Acrobat reader but the main issue is solved by adding `fill=none`, so I accept your answer. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I can not reproduce the shifting in TexShop, mac quickview, mac preview or mac Acrobat reader and also not here: https://smallpdf.com/pdf-reader. Why do you think that the problem is not TeXmaker?

Comment: Actually, I only experience this issue with Acrobat Reader. Neither on TeXmaker nor on any other viewer (online ones, at least) can I reproduce it. It seems that Acrobat does not work well with this kind of doc...